# Blobs in BlobStore in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I created blobs in GAE BlobStore, and these files created successfuly,the problem is when i try to serve these files using the BlobKey, i  got the content-length=0 as this:

```
Status: 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-AppEngine-BlobKey: crXwVb6vKoS8OykvgPmSew==
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip"
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

such that (test.zip)is the file that created in BlobStore,i checked the BlobStore in admin console and this file created successfully.
EDIT:
download.py code:

```
def mime_type(filename):
    return guess_type(filename)[0]
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self):

        blob_key = self.request.get('key')
        blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
        content_type1 =mime_type(blob_info.filename)
        save_as1 =  blob_info.filename
        self.send_blob(blob_key,content_type=content_type1,save_as=save_as1)



def main():

    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
            (r'/download.*', ServeHandler),
        ], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the key is exist in URL as:

```
http://localhost:8080/download.py?key=Es9f00P29wNTZoeL9ccS4g==
```

and i get it to get the blob from blobstore.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Peter Knego:Ok i will edit the question.

Comment: Where do you get the blobkey from? It looks like it's Base64 encoded.

Comment: @Peter Knego:firstly i creat zip archive file in BlobStore then get the key for this file and pass it through URL into download.py,and in this page i get the key and try to get the blob.

Comment: Try without `content_type` argument and with `save_as=True`

Comment: @Peter Knego:Thanks for your help,the problem was that i tried to print the blob_key inside the handler,i removed this statement and it worked.//content type and save as i need them

Answer (score 0):

According to the docstring:

```
Args:
  blob_key_or_info: BlobKey or BlobInfo record to serve.
  content_type: Content-type to override when known.
  save_as: If True, and BlobInfo record is provided, use BlobInfos
    filename to save-as.  If string is provided, use string as filename.
    If None or False, do not send as attachment.
  start: Start index of content-range to send.
  end: End index of content-range to send.  End index is inclusive.
  use_range: Use provided content range from requests Range header.
    Mutually exclusive to start and end.
```

Try changing your code to

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self):
    blob_key = BlobKey(urllib.unquote(self.request.get('key')))
    self.send_blob(blob_key, save_as=True)
```